# Why am I getting warning for functions as a React Child on this

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, ag-grid-react

what am I missing?  I cant spot it and my grids are not rendering properly.  I am getting warnings about functions not valid as a React Child.

```
  render() {
    return (
      <ModalDynamic
        defaultWidth={1200}
        defaultHeight={400}
        defaultX={100}
        defaultY={100}
        display={this.props.showPartsModal}
        title={
          "Parts for Invoice: " +
          (this.props.selectedHistory[0] !== undefined
            ? this.props.selectedHistory[0].invoice_number
            : "N/A")
        }
        dealerPath="[ 12345 ] Some Dealer"
        dismissAction={this.props.dismissAction}
      >
        <div
          //className="ag-theme-bootstrap container-fluid full-height zero-gap modal-container"
          className="ag-fresh container-fluid full-height zero-gap modal-container"
          style={{
            height: "calc(100%)",
            overflowX: "auto"
          }}
          id="viewPartsGrid"
        >
          <AgGridReact
            columnDefs={this.state.columns}
            rowData={this.props.selectedHistory}
            suppressMenuHide="true"
            suppressRowClickSelection="false"
            suppressColumnVirtualisation="false"
            sideBar="false"
            rowSelection="single"
            enableColResize="true"
            enableSorting="true"
            enableFilter="true"
            onGridReady={this.onGridReady}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="rnd-footer">
          <div className="rnd-left">{this.dealerLabel}</div>
          <div className="rnd-right">
            {this.state.gridAPI ? (
              <OverlayTrigger overlay={this.csvTip}>
                <Button
                  className="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
                  onClick={() =>
                    this.state.gridAPI.exportDataAsCsv({
                      fileName:
                        "Parts Invoice #" +
                        (this.props.selectedHistory[0].invoice_number
                          ? this.props.selectedHistory[0].invoice_number
                          : "N/A")
                    })
                  }
                >
                  <i className="fa fa-file-excel-o" />
                </Button>
              </OverlayTrigger>
            ) : null}
          </div>
        </div>
      </ModalDynamic>
    );
  }
}
```

The code compiles but the grid seems to not do what I am trying to write it to do.   Columns are not resizable and the window itself isn't either.

Comment: Could you check the method exportDataAsCsv is avaialbe and working properly of  this.state.gridAPI.exportDataAsCsv.

Comment: Hi @PalashKantiBachar, yea, this one is working correctly.

Comment: sidenote, instead of {this.state.gridAPI ? (<button />) : null} you could do {this.state.gridAPI && (<button />)}

Comment: also to find what causes the problem, the best way is to gradually delete code until the error is gone, this is how you can find what causes an error.

Answer (score 0):

I think this line may give you warning

```
 <div className="rnd-left">{this.dealerLabel}</div>
```

If this is a function that return some static value. Declare that in a new variable

Example
in render

```
const Button = <button onClick={this.yourmethod}>Click Me</button>

return (
   <Button>
)
```